# Hex.encodeHexString after AES encryption?

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am receiving encrypted message from server. They are using the following code for encryption

```
public static String encrypt(String plaintext, String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] pk = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pk);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());
            return Hex.encodeHexString(encrypted);
    }
```

My doubt is, they are using **Hex.encodeHexString(encrypted)**. why they are using this line of code? I know it converts an array of bytes into an array of characters representing the hexadecimal values of each byte in order. can't they send the encrypted text directly with out using **Hex.encodeHexString**? Can any one please give any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypted data is an array of arbitrary bytes. If it has to be passed by means supporting only printable strings such as XML or JSON this will be a problem. In order to deal with that binary data is encoded to form a printable string. However, [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding is used more often for this purpose.

Then prior to decrypting string has to be converted back to byte array with [Hex.decode()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decode%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Thanks. If I don't want printable string I am directly decrypting the bytes. Then don't I want this this encoding?.

Comment: byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes()); In this line plaintext.getbytes() actually does UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: `plaintext` here is a data to be encrypted, getBytes() encodes to platform default charset, not necessary to UTF-8 and `encrypted` is non-printable byte array.

Comment: yes. Even the non printable byte array can be send across the network and receiver is able receive the byte array with out any loss? If yes means I can decrypt it back?

Comment: Sure, you can decrypt it back.